# How to use MapProxy with OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

[MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/) looks rather promissing for my application. I think it is cool, that it:

> accelerates existing WMS 10 to 100 times

etc. But I could not find on the web any example on how to use it with OpenLayers 3 code base.

Comment: do you get the answer? please share here, I am also looking for it